# How to arrange entries from Ancestry tree in dropdown list in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a dropdown list which is populated with data from a table that is using ancestry.

I want to arrange the data in the list, so that the entries are grouped together with their siblings, and under their parents.

This code is working, but doesn't arrange the entries:

`<%= builder.select("id", Location.all.collect {|l| [ l.name_nb, l.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>`

I have tried this line:

`<%= builder.select("id", Location.arrange.collect {|l| [ l.name_nb, l.id ] }, { :include_blank => true }) %>`

Then I get the message:
undefined method `name_nb' for #

What am I doing wrong? How can I arrange the entries?

Comment: Check out the solutions from [ancestry's wiki](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/Creating-a-selectbox-for-a-form-using-ancestry)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my application i have 4 depth level model. This is a code that im use for dropdown.

Controller:

```
before_filter :collection_for_parent_select, :except => [:index, :show]

  def collection_for_parent_select
    @categories = ancestry_options(Category.unscoped.arrange(:order => 'name')) {|i| "#{'-' * i.depth} #{i.name}" }
  end

  def ancestry_options(items)
    result = []
    items.map do |item, sub_items|
      result << [yield(item), item.id]
      #this is a recursive call:
      result += ancestry_options(sub_items) {|i| "#{'-' * i.depth} #{i.name}" }
    end
    result
  end
```

View, with haml and formtastics:

```
= f.input :parent_id, :as => :select, :collection => @categories
```

P.S. I know this is not the efficient solution, but it works. Also take a look at ancestry [wiki](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry/wiki/Creating-a-selectbox-for-a-form-using-ancestry)

Comment: Thank's a lot! In the form I didn't get the :parent_id thing to work, but I used a string with the name of the field instead, and now it works very well!

Answer (score 3):

Update to @mikhail's answer:

```
#app/views/your_view.html.erb
<%= f.select(:category_ids, nested_dropdown(Category.all.arrange)) %>

#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def nested_dropdown(items)
    result = []
    items.map do |item, sub_items|
        result << [('- ' * item.depth) + item.name, item.id]
        result += nested_dropdown(sub_items) unless sub_items.blank?
    end
    result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (Rails 4):
      <%= f.collection_select :parent_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>

Comment: It's missing siblings (or indents). A plain list does not look as a tree.