# ancestry and rails_admin, dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I'm trying out Rails_Admin. For a set of articles, I'm using ancestry. Therefore, I would like to create a dropdown list in the new&edit pages, making me able to select the right parent article.

My current config:

```
  config.model Article do
  #   # Found associations:

    # Found columns:
      field :id, :integer 
      field :title, :string 
      field :description, :text 
      field :content, :text do
        ckeditor true
      end
      #field :created_at, :datetime 
      #field :updated_at, :datetime 
      field :ancestry, :enum do
        @articles = Article.scoped
        @articles.arrange(:order => :created_at)
      end
    # Sections:
    list do; end
    export do; end
    show do; end
    edit do; end
    create do; end
    update do; end
  end
```

So, pretty standard, except the :enum field. I must be doing something wrong here. Any ideas?

I already saw [How to arrange entries from Ancestry tree in dropdown list in Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674754/how-to-arrange-entries-from-ancestry-tree-in-dropdown-list-in-rails-3) but unless I'm mistaking that's quite some queries they're doing. I would like to make use of the Arrange feature.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote this plugin to manage ancestry with rails_admin: [rails_admin_nestable](https://github.com/dalpo/rails_admin_nestable).
I hope will be useful.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to achive what you want would be

In your model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry
  attr_accessor :parent_id
  #...
end
```

next add the right field to config.model

```
field :parent_id, :enum do
  enum do
    Article.select(:id).map{|article| article.id} #this is just an example though
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Config the model in rails_admin as follows:

```
  config.model Article do
    list do
      field :title
      field :parent do
        formatted_value do
          value.title if value
        end
      end
    end

    show do
      field :title
      field :parent do
        formatted_value do
          value.title if value
        end
      end
    end

    edit do
      field :title
      field :ancestry, :enum do
        enum do
          except = bindings[:object].id
          Article.where("id != ?", except).map { |c| [ c.title, c.id ] }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: small update: except = bindings[:object].id.nil? ? 0 : bindings[:object].id

Answer (score 0):

Actually for me the solution was:

```
before_validation :check_ancestry

def check_ancestry
  if self.ancestry.blank?
    self.ancestry=nil
  end
end

def percorso
  p=""
  self.ancestors.each do |n|
    p+=n.title + " -> "
  end
  p+=self.title
end

rails_admin do
  edit do
    field :ancestry, :enum do
      enum do
        except = bindings[:object].id.nil? ? 0 : bindings[:object].id
        Article.where("id != ?", except).map { |c| [ c.percorso, c.ancestry? ? "#{c.ancestry}/#{c.id}":"#{c.id}" ]}
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I put this in my `config/initializers/rails_admin.rb`

```
    config.model 'MyModel' do
      edit do
        include_all_fields
        field :parent_id, :enum do
          enum do
            MyModel.all.map{|model| [model.name, model.id ]}.to_a
          end
        end
       exclude_fields :ancestry
      end
    end
```